# fundamental theorem of calculus and chain rule

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) \in (0,1)$ for every $x \in (0,1)$.

I want to take the first and second derivative of $F(x) = \left(\int_0^xf(t)dt\right)^2 - \int_0^x(f(t))^3dt$ and will use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule to do it. I just want to make sure that I'm doing it right because I haven't seen any examples that apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to a function like this.

$F'(x) = 2\left(\int_0^xf(t)dt\right)f(x) - (f(x))^3$ by the chain rule and fund thm of calc.

$F''(x) = 2\left(f(x)\right)^2 + 2f'(x)\left(\int_0^xf(t)dt\right) - 3f'(x)(f(x))^2 $ by the product rule, chain rule and fund thm of calc.

Comment: Yep, that's right!